# bootstrap navbar not working correctly

Tags: html, eclipse, twitter-bootstrap

Im using tomcat 9, java, bootstrap to develop a online forum. Suddenly the navigation is not working, i tried a few things but no luck. In the chrome network inspector tab everything seems fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="static/css/myCss.css" rel="stylesheet">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link href="static/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="static/css/customIndex.css" rel="stylesheet">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="static/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
<title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="./index.jsp">Index</a></li>
        <li><a href="./profile.jsp">Profile</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="./LogoutServlet">Logout</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

screenshot:
[localhost:screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GtgG.png)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps the path to your bootstrap.min.css is collapsed? I just added this link to your header 
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">` and pointed to the `data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"`. It seems working now.

```html
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="static/css/myCss.css" rel="stylesheet">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link href="static/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="static/css/customIndex.css" rel="stylesheet">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="static/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="./index.jsp">Index</a></li>
        <li><a href="./profile.jsp">Profile</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="./LogoutServlet">Logout</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: Yes ! :D i added rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"  and it is working now. But can you explain me why i cant load the css file locally. Thanks

Comment: Because you need to go http://getbootstrap.com and download bootstrap to your localhost, other wise just add the link as I do.

Comment: i have provided all the bootstrap stuff in a static folder and added <link href="static/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">..

Answer (score 5):

The navbar is not working because of some problem with bootstrap itself.

Bootstrap's current version at the date of posting this answer is 4.3.x and it seems to be having some problems.
The navbar is not working properly and neither is `.page-header`(page-header class. And I'm not sure if other stuff is working fine in this version).

Also the CDN for minified bootstrap css `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">` that is on bootstrap's website doesn't work correctly either.

The solution is using older version (version 3.3.5 I know works correctly) of bootstrap which I know is not an efficient solution, but it works. 
Or you can use this CDN for minified bootstrap css `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">` . It will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

the nav bar works depended on their specified bootstrap cdn css versions

for eg:-

if we open bootstrap site

we can see different Toggler styles

(link:https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar)

scroll down to reach toggler

*code*

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0 ml-8">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

this is work on 4.0.0 cdn css versions , so each one of the example in the bootstrap site is specified a version , so use that version ,we don't see which version are use for this , check all versions  in your text ide